# How can I visualize TensorRT network graph?

Tags: neural-network, tensorrt

Our current flow: Conversation of `tf2`->`onnx`->`TensorRT` (all`16` and `32` and `8` bits options)

Is there an existing tool like https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron (or any other way) to see the output model of `TensorRT`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can now visualize tensorrt engine graphs using https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/tree/main/tools/experimental/trt-engine-explorer

It also offers other info about the engine.

Answer (score 0):

Is the goal to visualize it after the compression from onnx/TensorRT? Or just to visualize it in general? You can always just use the [keras tool](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/plot_model).

I believe you can use a TensorRT model as well with netron, based on this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hum7awcBffY&ab_channel=ArdianUmam).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info. But I'm looking for a way to visualize the graph in TensorRT format. We do the optimization inside TensorRT. We do not use the tf_trt binding any more

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this, because the TensorRT model (engine) is optimized for certain hardware (A specific NVIDIA GPU architecture). It is already "compiled" (similar to coreML `mlmodel`'s are compiled to `mlmodelc`, where as TensorFlow (or TFLite) models are not "compiled" for specific hardware.

From the NVIDIA forums: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/visualizing-tensorrt-engine/69032

> I assume you are asking for something analogous to tensorboard or netron? Unfortunately, I’m not aware a way for TRT.

From the creator of Netron (lutzroeder):

> Unless this format is documented not sure much can be done here. Netron has a browser-only version so even if a Python or C++ API existed for supporting non-inference scenarios it wouldn't be useful.

---

You can still of course visualize the ONNX model right before you create the TensorRT one. TensorRT just needs an optimized model, so I don't expect it to be different.

Comment: Hey, although its compiled. Nvidia still has the information about the layers themself. Actually when `compiling` it does brouteforcing to explore different ways of "complication". We already use Nertron to see the output of ONNX. But when converting to `int8` it wont be exactly the same.